# how to Use created SQL variable in the same query

Tags: postgresql, column-alias

I have the following query:

```
   SELECT target,
   
   CASE
       WHEN var_10 >1.5 AND var_10 <2.5 THEN 1 
   END as var_10_bck,
```

Then I want to use this new created variable "var_10_bck" in the same query that continues as :

```
   CASE
       WHEN var_10_bck <2 THEN 0
   END as var_10_new

   FROM database
```

Comment: As a side note: that's not a "variable" it's a column (or column alias). And you select FROM a table, not a database.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name funny fuct, my table is called 'database'

Comment: That's a really disturbing naming convention